# hms function kicking out NAs

Tags: r, type-conversion, lubridate, posixct

Keep getting this warning message:

> ```
> Warning message:
> In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
>   Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
> ```

And the function replaces all data in my character vector to `NA`.

I've tried running `hms()` function through `lubridate` package and tried again using `POSIXct`

```
combined$start<- c("8:45" "12:10" "16:00")

combined$start <- as.character(combined$start)

combined$start <- hms(combined$start)
```

I'd like the characters in `combined$start` to be converted to `hms` but I only get `NA when I try to run the last line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any seconds in `combined$start`, so try just using hm.

```
combined$start <- hm(combined$start)
```

I also noticed that you do not have commas when you are creating `combined$start`, so try changing the line to:

```
combined$start<- c("8:45", "12:10", "16:00")
```